# General formula of repeated roots.

Tags: arithmetic, radicals, nested-radicals

Prove that $$\underbrace{\sqrt{k\sqrt{k\sqrt{k\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{k}}}}}}_{n\text { times}}=k^{1-1/2^n}$$
How do I derive this formula?

Comment: Glibly: induction.

Comment: Try to rewrite this expession using $k^{1/2}$.

Comment: Take logarithms (you could try base $k$)

Comment: what an interesting question!

Comment: if k = 0 left side is 0 right side is not defined.

Comment: @djechlin How so? If $k = 0$, we have:
$$\underbrace{\sqrt{0\sqrt{0\sqrt{0\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{0}}}}}}_{n\text { times}}=0^{1-1/2^n}$$
Which simplifies to $0=0^{1-1/2^n}$, and unless $n = 0$ ($1-1/2^0 = 0$), we get $0=0^1$ which is obviously true.

Comment: @ColeJohnson word.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\underbrace{\sqrt{k\sqrt{k\sqrt{k\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{k}}}}}}_{n\text { times}} = \sqrt{k}\times\sqrt[4]{k}\times \ldots \times \sqrt[2^n]{k} = k^{1/2}\times k^{1/4}\times \ldots \times k^{1/2^n} = \\ = k^{\Large\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2^n}} = k^{\Large1-\frac{1}{2^n}}$$

Answer (score 8):

Base case: $\sqrt{k}=k^{1/2}=k^{1-1/2^1}$.

Induction step: let $a_n$ be the LHS when there are $n$ square root signs. If $a_n=k^{1-1/2^n}$, then
$$
a^2_{n+1}=ka_n=kk^{1-1/2^n}=k^{2-1/2^n}\implies a_{n+1}=k^{1-1/2^{n+1}}.
$$

Answer (score 6):

Take the logarithm (as already suggested in comments):
$$ \frac{1}{2}\left(\ln k +  \frac{1}{2}\left(\ln k + \frac{1}{2}\left( \ln k + \ldots \right) \right)\right)$$
$$ =\left(\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2^n}\right)\ln k$$
$$ =\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^n}\right) \ln k.$$

Answer (score 2):

The first $k$ is powered by $\frac{1}{2}$, the second by $\frac{1}{2^2}$ the $n$-therm is then $k^{\frac{1}{2^n}}$ then the expression is equal to:

$$k^{\frac{1}{2^1}}\cdot k^{\frac{1}{2^2}}\cdot \dots  k^{\frac{1}{2^n}}=k^{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^i}}$$